# Bug in bower-installer, can't find bower.json

Tags: json, bower

Tired of bower downloading everything in each repo I install, I setup [bower-installer](https://github.com/blittle/bower-installer).

https://scotch.io/tutorials/only-grab-the-files-you-need-while-using-bower

However after running `bower-installer` I get this strange error:

```
bower-installer
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower-installer/bower-installer.js:56
    throw createError('Neither bower.json nor component.json present', 'ENOEN
```

[image]

My bower.json file is there, and what's in it below:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "main": "app.js",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "authors": [
    "Leon"
  ],
  "description": "My app",
  "keywords": [
    "tags",
    "manage"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "me.com",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.12.1",
    "angular-loader": "1.2.x",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2.x",
    "angular-route": "1.2.x",
    "angular-scroll": "~0.6.5",
    "chartist": "~0.7.3",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.4",
    "angular": "~1.3.15"
  },
  "install": {
    "path": "libs",
    "sources": {
      "angular": "bower_components/angular/angular.min.js",
      "bootstrap": "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "chartist": [
        "bower_components/chartist/dist/chartist.min.js",
        "bower_components/chartist/dist/chartist.min.css",
      ],
      "angular-scroll": "bower_components/angular-scroll/angular-scroll.min.js",
      "angular-route": "bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js",
      "angular-mocks": "bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js",
      "angular-loader": "bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js",
      "angular-bootstrap": [
        "bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js",
        "bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js",
        "bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js",
        "bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is bower.json in the right directory? Where does bower-installer look for it?

Comment: @TimCastelijns yea in the right path, checkout the screenshot I just added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bower.json is incorrect, this part

```
"chartist": [
  "bower_components/chartist/dist/chartist.min.js",
  "bower_components/chartist/dist/chartist.min.css",
],
```

should be

```
"chartist": [
  "bower_components/chartist/dist/chartist.min.js",
  "bower_components/chartist/dist/chartist.min.css"
],
```

So drop the last comma. That comma makes the json invalid and therefore the bower installer can't parse it. I verified this with your bower.json and it works fine after removing the comma.

Comment: Thanks! That was it :D Sweet.... no more having to manually delete folders I don't need hehe